# How to remove style from previously clicked list item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to make a calendar so that when you click the number of the day, 3 booking times appear below for the user to pick from. My issue is that with my code if you select the day it will style it to be green, but I don't know how to remove the style from that day if the user were to pick a different day. Any help would be great.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIY6H.png)

HTML:

```
<body onLoad="getMonth()">
<div id="container">
    <p id="month">MONTH</p>
    <div id="fullDiv">
        <ul class="days">
            <li>SUN</li>
            <li>MON</li>
            <li>TUE</li>
            <li>WED</li>
            <li>THUR</li>
            <li>FRI</li>
            <li>SAT</li>
            <li onclick="check(1);remStyle(event);">1</li>
            <li onclick="check(2);remStyle(event);">2</li>
            <li onclick="check(3);remStyle(event);">3</li>
            <li onclick="check(4);remStyle(event);">4</li>
            <li onclick="check(5);remStyle(event);">5</li>
            <li onclick="check(6);remStyle(event);">6</li>
            <li onclick="check(7);remStyle(event);">7</li>
            <li onclick="check(8);remStyle(event);">8</li>
            <li onclick="check(9);remStyle(event);">9</li>
            <li onclick="check(10);remStyle(event);">10</li>
            <li onclick="check(11);remStyle(event);">11</li>
            <li onclick="check(12);remStyle(event);">12</li>
            <li onclick="check(13);remStyle(event);">13</li>
            <li onclick="check(14);remStyle(event);">14</li>
            <li onclick="check(15);remStyle(event);">15</li>
            <li onclick="check(16);remStyle(event);">16</li>
            <li onclick="check(17);remStyle(event);">17</li>
            <li onclick="check(18);remStyle(event);">18</li>
            <li onclick="check(19);remStyle(event);">19</li>
            <li onclick="check(20);remStyle(event);">20</li>
            <li onclick="check(22);remStyle(event);">22</li>
            <li onclick="check(23);remStyle(event);">23</li>
            <li onclick="check(24);remStyle(event);">24</li>
            <li onclick="check(25);remStyle(event);">25</li>
            <li onclick="check(26);remStyle(event);">26</li>
            <li onclick="check(27);remStyle(event);">27</li>
            <li onclick="check(28);remStyle(event);">28</li>
            <li onclick="check(29);remStyle(event);">29</li>
            <li onclick="check(30);remStyle(event);">30</li>
            <li onclick="check(31);remStyle(event);">31</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function check(value) {
  day = value;
  document.getElementById("bookingTimes").style.visibility = "visible";
  var content = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  if (day == value) {
    content[day + 6].style.backgroundColor = "#1abc9c";
    content[day + 6].style.color = "#ecf0f1";
  }

  return day;
}
```

Comment: What have you programmed your code to do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to the element when selected and then remove the class from all elements with a querySelectorAll call.

```
.selected
{
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

```
function check(value) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".selected").forEach(x => x.className = "");
  day = value;
  document.getElementById("bookingTimes").style.visibility = "visible";
  var content = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  if (day == value) {
    content[day + 6].className = "selected";
    
  }

  return day;
}
```

Or you could keep track of the selected element.

```
var selected;

function check(value) {
  
  if(typeof(selected) != "undefined")
  {
    selected.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    selected.style.color = "black";
  }

  day = value;
  document.getElementById("bookingTimes").style.visibility = "visible";
  var content = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  if (day == value) {
    content[day + 6].style.backgroundColor = "#1abc9c";
    content[day + 6].style.color = "#ecf0f1";
    selected = content[day + 6];
  }

  return day;
}
```